# If page has children show sub nav

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress theme and I'm looking to show the sub nav only if the current page has children, I'm using the code below which works great, but doesn't have an if statement, which means it shows an empty menu on some pages.

```
<?php global $id;
        wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$id&show_date=modified&date_format=$date_format");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below :-

```
$kids = get_pages("child_of=$id");
if (count($kids) > 0) { wp_list_pages(...); }
```